# Use Python's unquote() for Node.js

Tags: python, node.js

I am receiving my data with the following format through a webhook.

```
{
  "Body": "Test+131415+5%2B5%3D10",
  "To": "whatsapp%3A%2B4915735992273",
  "From": "whatsapp%3A%2B491603817902",
}
```

In Python I could use the following functions to transform my data. However, I couldn't find a way with Node.js to get the same outcome.

```
def get_from(from: str) -> int:
    """
    Replace %xx escapes by their single-character equivalent.
    Only return the part that is behind the plus sign.
    """
    receiver = unquote(receiver).split("+")
    return receiver[1]


def get_body(body: str) -> str:
    """
    Replace %xx escapes by their single-character equivalent.
    _plus additionally replaces plus signs by spaces.
    """
    body = unquote_plus(body)
    return body
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

urlib.parse.unquote equivalent in nodejs is [unescape](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v12.x/api/querystring.html#querystring_querystring_unescape_str)

There is no equivalent for urlib.parse.unquote_plus in nodejs

But you can do it yourself as below

```
const { unescape } = require('querystring');

const data = {
  "Body": "Test+131415+5%2B5%3D10",
  "To": "whatsapp%3A%2B4915735992273",
  "From": "whatsapp%3A%2B491603817902",
};

function getFrom(from) {
  return unescape(from).split('+')[1];
}

function getBody(body) {
  return unescape(body.replace(/\+/g, ' '));
}

console.log(getFrom(data.From));
console.log(getBody(data.Body));
```